# Two buttons, one Activity

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have two buttons in my notification which opens the same activity but sending as extra different data. Do I really need to create 2 pending intents and 2 intents? There is maybe some shorten version of this?

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ResponseActivity.class); //same
        intent1.putExtra("RES","a");
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP   | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ResponseActivity.class); //same
        intent2.putExtra("RES","b"); //but different
        intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP   | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .addAction(0, "A", pendingIntent1) 
                .addAction(0, "B", pendingIntent2) 
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setContentTitle(userDB.getName())
                .setContentText(smallText)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your code. Your code will end up setting the same `PendingIntent` with the same `Intent` on both buttons. This is because the  "extras" are not considered when comparing the `Intent`s to determine if a `PendingIntent` already exists for a given `Intent`. In your case, the 2 `Intent`s look the same, so the 2 calls to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` will return the same `PendingIntent`.

You need to change your code to look like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResponseActivity.class); //same
    intent.putExtra("RES","a");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Update the "extra" in the Intent
    intent.putExtra("RES","b"); //but different
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I used a single `Intent` to produce 2 different `PendingIntent`s. The key here is to use different values for the `requestCode` (which is the 2nd parameter to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`). This ensures that you get 2 different `PendingIntent`s.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

An Intent isn't a call to open an activity, but is actually more of a message to an activity (which in most cases is a message to start the activity).

And so unfortunately, if you want two different messages, you need two different intents.

Answer (score -1):

Considering `putEtra()` returns the `Intent` you could shorten your code like this :

```
public static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Intent intent) {
  return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResponseActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

.addAction(0, "A", getPendingIntent(intent.putExtra("RES","a"))) 
.addAction(0, "B", getPendingIntent(intent.putExtra("RES","b")))
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work, it always add "a" and then "b". So the extra is always "b"

Comment: That means you have to use 2 differents Intent